# boost::asio::connect() not found

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

as the title says, my compiler (Ubuntu 64bit) tells me that boost::asio::connect() is not an element of boost::asio. In my code I try to call

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
tcp::resolver::query query(argv[1], "daytime");
tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
tcp::socket socket(io_service);
boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);
```

The libraries (1.48.00) are installed and everything else is found. Any ideas why this is not found?

Include files:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
```

Comment: Your `#include` files?

Comment: Did you try `#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>`?

Comment: This file I don't have... don't know why. Installed Boost via apt-get. This file should be included in <boost/asio.hpp> anyway, shouldn't it?

Comment: My bad. You don't need to explicitly include `boost/asio/connect.hpp`. `boost/asio.hpp` includes it anyway.

Comment: I now created boost/asio/connect.hpp by hand. How come this file was missing? Now it misses boost/asio/impl/connect.hpp which is included by boost/asio/connect.hpp

Comment: It seems libboost-iostreams1.48-dev was missing! Now it is finding everything and it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may get `libboost-all-dev` if you use Boost extensively.

Comment: That's what I installed (99% sure) - so I didn't expect a package to be missing! So thanks a lot for ht help to find that out!

Comment: Can you please answer your own question and mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by installing libboost-iostreams1.48-dev via apt-get, which was missing. That installed all the missing headers and libs and the connect() function was found then.